# Creating Quintile (Percentile) Array and need to switch corresponding numbers

Tags: arrays, excel, percentile

Im using excel and i need to take columns and assign them to their corresponding percentile (1-5). I need 1 to indicate that its essentially "good" or in the top percentile, and 5 to indicate that it is "bad" or in the bottom 20%. I have used the "MATCH" function but that only works where it is flip flopped and 5 is the top percentile and 1 is the lowest percentile. How do I switch this

this is the code I have so far
=MATCH(T2,PERCENTILE($T$2:$T$1101,{5,4,3,2,1}/5),-1)

Comment: It's better to share your code/formula, then we can offer suggestions.

Comment: This is the code I have so far=MATCH(T3,PERCENTILE($T$2:$T$1101,{5,4,3,2,1}/5),-1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in first row and fill down:

```
=IF(A1<=PERCENTILE.INC(A:A,0.2),"Bad",IF(A1>=PERCENTILE.EXC(A:A,0.8),"Good",""))
```

Answer (score 0):

This one has worked for me perfectly - I manually adjusted the quintiles aorund and then played with the formula:

```
MATCH(T2,PERCENTILE($T$2:$T$1101,1-{5,4,3,2,1}/5),1)),"")
```

I added the -1 before the array to create a whole number.

Then, changed the -1 at the end to +1 in order to create a result greater than the figure.